# Determine conjugate function

Tags: optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=e^x$. Determine $f^*(y)$.

I try to use some inequalities to get supremum but it is impossible. Seemingly, I must consider some cases of $x$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $f^*$?

Comment: I assume he means $f^*(y)\triangleq \sup_x\langle y,x\rangle - f(x)$, given the title.

Comment: @Abel: It is like what Michael says. $f^*(y)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left\{xy-f(x)\right\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f^*(y)=\textstyle\sup_x \langle y, x \rangle - e^x.$$
Since the supremum involves a smooth function we can examine the derivative:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(yx-e^x) = y-e^x = 0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad x=\log y~~\text{if}~~y>0.$$
So if $y>0$, at least,
$$f^*(y) = y\log y - y.$$
If $y=0$, then the supremum is $0$; if
$y<0$, then the supremum is $+\infty$. (In both cases, let $x\rightarrow-\infty$.) So the final answer is
$$f^*(y)=\begin{cases} y\log y - y & y > 0 \\ 0 & y = 0 \\ +\infty & y < 0 \end{cases}$$
If you don't like extended-valued functions just drop the $y<0$ case and state that
$$\mathop{\textrm{dom}}(f^*) = \mathbb{R}_+.$$

Comment: why using derivative for y>0, I can't understand. Besides, what will happen if $x\to+\infty$

Comment: $x$ is the independent variable inside the supremum. The proper value of $x$ is the one that $yx-e^x$. There's no way that it can approach infinity, because $x\rightarrow+\infty$ means $yx-e^x\rightarrow-\infty$.

Comment: Hung Tran asks: Could you tell me more detail about the case $y>0$, why computing $f^*$ by finding extreme point of $x$?

Comment: Because it is necessary to compute $\sup_x yx-e^x$. How else would you propose to solve it?